# No renderiza la vista: message: 'Could not render view

Tags: nodejs, ejs

**Me presenta el siguiente mensaje de error:**

error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
{
message: 'Could not render view "/pages/admin/lista-clientes".  Tried locating view file @ "C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\views\pages\admin\lista-clientes". Layout configured as "layouts/layout", so tried using layout @ "C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\views\layouts\layout")',
code: 'E_VIEW_FAILED',
status: 500,
view: SailsView {
defaultEngine: 'ejs',
ext: '.ejs',
name: '/pages/admin/lista-clientes',
root: 'C:\Datos\Cursos\Sails\Tfotos\views',
engine: [Function: wrapper],
path: undefined
},
inspect: [Function]

**Adjunto la vista (lista-clientes.ejs) que intento presentar:**

```
div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
  
      <% flash.get('mensaje').forEach(function (msg) { %>
      <div class="alert alert-info text-center" role="alert">
        <%=msg%>
      </div>
      <% }) %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <% clientes.forEach( cliente => { %>
    <div class="col-md-4 my-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 my-2">
      <div class="card">
        <h5 class="card-header bg-info text-white">
          <%=cliente.id%>
          <%=cliente.alias%>
          <%=cliente.nombre%>
        </h5>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">BODY TEXT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-center">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 my-2"></div>
    <% }) %>
  </div>
```

**Archivo de dependencias:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "postgresql": "0.0.1",
    "sails": "^1.0.2",
    "sails-hook-flash": "^0.2.2",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3"
```

**Si requieren algún dato adicional para su soporte, estoy atento.**

PD: Estamos aprendiendo aún, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema fue solo con el path en el archivo del controlador, no estaba la ruta completa de la vista.

Estaba así:

```
return respuesta.view('/admin/lista-clientes', { clientes });
```

Y funciono así:

```
return respuesta.view('pages/admin/lista-clientes', { clientes });
```